# Undoing last addremove in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I typed

```
$ hg addremove
```

but later realized that some of the files should not be part of the commit. What I should have done was to add these files to .hgignore and after that run addremove and commit.

Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have not commited yet just use `hg forget fileToForget` or use Tortoise to remove the files.

If you have committed and you don't mind the files to be part of history, just forget them and commit again.

If you don't want them to be part of your repository history, and if commiting them is the very last operation you've made, you can try to rollback (use `hg rollback` or go in the recovery menu in Tortoise). You will have to forget the file and then commit again

If you're dealing with too many files, you can try to automate the task by getting a list of all added files, forgetting  them, modify you `.hgignore` and do the `addremove` again.

Example of the first step in powershell with no commit made

```
hg status --added --no-status | foreach-object {hg forget $_};
```

Comment: For linux type `hg status --added --no-status | xargs hg forget`.

Comment: Try this from another answer `hg forget "set:added()"` which worked for me.

Comment: @DanielSokolowski That doesn't work if there are spaces in the filenames - use `hg status --added --no-status | xargs -d '\n' hg forget` instead.

Answer (score -1):

To undo an **addremove** you did not commit yet simply run:

```
$ hg revert --all
```

Comment: Assuming there were no other changes besides the effects of the `addremove`.

Comment: You're right - I assumed that 'addremove' was the only command you want to undo.

Comment: @Alex This can be dangerous as @Edward mentioned. Someone using this command will lose all workspace changes. `hg forget` is the right way to do this. Please see the answer from @CedricRup